# Reorganizing repeated rows with one unique value into columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I've got a dataframe of chemical assay data that's formatted rather poorly. The convention is to have a single row containing the ID, spatial data, and other attribute data with the concentrations all following under columns for gold, silver, zinc, (their columns being labelled Au_PPM, Ag_PPM, Zn_PPM). However, this data set has separate rows for each element in sample, with all the other data being repeated.
How can I merge duplicate rows that have the same sample ID and attribute info, but unique VALUE (eg. 0.4) and CHEM_UNIT columns (eg. Ag_PPM), where the CHEM UNIT becomes the column name, and the VALUES from each row populate the appropriate CHEM_UNIT column?
Basically just trying to condense the repeated data into a single row.

Sample from the df:

```
    SAMPLE_NO   SAMPLE_SOURCE   DH_DEPTH_FROM   DH_DEPTH_TO LONGITUDE_GDA2020   LATITUDE_GDA2020    VALUE   CHEM_UNIT
0   3580567 A full face slice of core   575.0   577.0   136.692456  -28.878919  135.0   Ba_PPM
1   3580567 A full face slice of core   575.0   577.0   136.692456  -28.878919  0.0 Ag_PPM
2   3580567 A full face slice of core   575.0   577.0   136.692456  -28.878919  0.0 As_PPM
3   3580567 A full face slice of core   575.0   577.0   136.692456  -28.878919  0.0 Au_PPM
4   3580567 A full face slice of core   575.0   577.0   136.692456  -28.878919  2.5 Be_PPM
```

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you please send a link to a csv file for the data? That would make solving your issue a lot easier

Comment: It's a 5 GB csv that wouldn't be appropriate to send. However, I could provide more sample data if that's what you mean.

Comment: yep, thats what i meant

Answer (score 0):

You could use `df.drop_duplicates()`. [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

Comment: This would drop all the assay values except the first.
The goal is to keep the first row in the sample, add fields based on the CHEM_UNIT column, and populate it with the value, turning each sample series into a single row.